# Css Less - Need to access nested elements

Tags: css, less

I am in the midst of setting up some new typography for a project. I'm using Less, so decided to use the functionality to set up some styles - here's an example:

```
.serif
{
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    font-style:normal;
    font-weight:400;

    &.body1
    {
        font-size:1.4rem;

        .mq-min(@desktop-bp;
        {
            font-size:1.3rem;
        });
    }
}
```

What I want to be able to achieve is to call any inner combination whilst inheriting the outer parent styles, like this:

```
body
{
    .serif.body1;
}
```

I've tried many different combination with and without the & but have been unable to get the required output I want. Here's what I'm getting currently:

```
body {
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 1.4rem;
}

body.body1 {
  font-size: 1.4rem;
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 960px) {
  body.body1 {
    font-size: 1.3rem;
  }
}
```

Ultimately, this is what I'd have to type in manually for the body style to work as required:

```
body {
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 1.4rem;
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 960px) {
  body {
    font-size: 1.3rem;
  }
}
```

Comment: Please also add the CSS result you need to get. (as I can guess the Less code you need is just `.serif.body {.serif.body1;}` but it's hard to tell for sure w/o seeing the CSS result you're actually expecting to get).

Comment: @seven-phases-max - thanks for the reply. You're correct as that will I beleieve give me the anser I want - the question is - how do I get from body.body1 to serif.body1?

Comment: @seven-phases-max - just realised that you might not be fully aware - there are other nested styles inside .serif -  so .body2 etc

Comment: Code is worth thousands words ("get something in/to/from something" is too blurrish)... Just put the desired CSS result into the Q and they'll answer. (notice that we can know your "what I'm getting currently" result simply by compiling your Less snippet, but there's no way to know the CSS result you have in mind untill you post it).

Comment: @seven-phases-max - I've added the requirement to the post

Comment: so you mean that you need a way to define a style inside `.serif` so that such style to be used as a mixin would also borrow `.serif` properties? Hmm.. No, I'm afraid this is not how mixins work... (if you point to `.serif.body1` only its inner styles are considered and any outer styles are irrelevant (that is: to copy *both* `serif` and `.serif.body1` property sets you need to reference *both* on their own, i.e. `.serif` *and* `.serif.body1`). No magic symbol at `.body1` can change this).)

Comment: What you need is actually possible in various other ways but exact code would depend on what the `.body1` rueset is supposed to mean in the initial snippet - for example, should it really appear in the output CSS as a child element of `.serif`?

Comment: The whole reason for structuring it this way is to enable quick and east styling on other classes. .body1 refers to serif - there could be another body1 for .sans-serif, so this needs to be managed. However, if you can think of a better way, I'm all ears

Comment: If `.body1` does not only really appear as class in you HTML but only to be used as mixin for other styles then you'd better to define it as a [parametric mixin](http://lesscss.org/features/#mixins-parametric-feature) instead. Then the solution becomes as simple as [this](https://gist.github.com/seven-phases-max/37a11e0b89b7fb450c5e). If contrary `.body1` ruleset has to be present in the output CSS (thus you really have some `<... class="serif body1 ...>` HTML thing to apply this style to) the code would be slightly different.

Comment: I think the example you've highlighted does the job - thanks for sticking with me.

Answer (score 0):

So basing on a few clarifications in above comments (e.g. `body1` class does not have to appear in the resulting CSS and is used only as a mixin), the following modification does the trick:

```
.serif {
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    font-style:   normal;
    font-weight:  400;

    .body() {
        .serif;
        font-size: 1.4rem;

        @media only screen and (min-width: 960px) {
            font-size: 1.3rem;
        }
    }
}

body {
    .serif.body;
}
```